# Using Code Access Security without the GAC

Tags: c#, security, code-access-security

I am wondering if it is possible to use Code Access Security, and a custom permission class (and attribute), without having to register the assembly that the attribute is in, in the GAC.

At the moment, I get a TypeLoadException when the method with my attribute is called, and I can't seem to get around it. Everything i've read seems to imply that you need to use the GAC in order to achieve this.

Does anyone have any insight?

I've tried to acheive the same end-goal with AOP using PostSharp or AspectDNG, but both of those add an addition dependency to my product, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say yes (but cannot be sure without more details of what and how you are doing). We have custom permissions/roles with CAS here and nothing is in the GAC wrt to security. Ultimetly CAS will need to access your assemblies' implementation of IPrincipal. Have you looked at the fusion log to determine where your assemblies are being probed?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. It seems you simply cannot have your custom attributes be child classes, and you must have only one constructor, which takes on a SecurityAction.

Comment: Do have an example - I wish to understand this more please?